# Bulit in Exceptions available in java

Tags: java

I was reading about exception handling in java. Found that there are severaly types of exception classes in java. I wanted to know **what is exact number of Exception (Built-in) class available in java**.I am using java 7.

Comment: Do you really care about the count ? If YES, please count them.

Comment: Depends on what you consider to be Java.  Do you want to include JavaEE?  Or only the classes shipped with the  base JDK?  How about JavaFX? Java Web Start? I'm not sure this question has any real meaning as the answer can change at any time.

Comment: @JimGarrison exactly. Also - should we count internal/private/package private/unsafe `Exception`s too? And, first and foremost, *what is the sense of this question, what is the intention?* OP, *what are you trying to achieve by counting them?*

Comment: @vaxquis : I am simply updating my knowledge related to 'Exceptions'. What is wrong in that if we have experts here to answer the question.No need to put harsh comments and dislikes if you dont like the question. I presume u never had thought this type of question in ur mind.

Comment: @JimGarrison sir I am considering only JDK.

Comment: @user2234885 knowing the count of something is hardly a knowledge when it implies completely nothing. SO is a *knowledge* base - OTOH, you question brings no actual knowledge, i.e. is extremely trivia-like and unlikely to help anyone with any actual problem. The very idea of harsh comments and downvotes is to **discourage** questions such as this one. Also - yes, this type of questions doesn't bother me, and I seldom have them in my mind - for the very same reason I seldom wonder *"how many letters `A` are there in source code of Linux?"*. **When** I have one of those, I check it myself.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find out all pre-defined exceptions in java you should read the documentation. In [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) for `Exception` class, there is part that lists the **Direct Known Subclasses:**

[image]

So you can count them or whatever. Then you can find out about the sub-classes of each one recursively.

There are 74 direct sub-classes are listed in java documentation in java 7. Also there are a huge number of sub-classes can be found in the hierarchy of direct sub-classes as well. And it's obvious that this number of Exceptions can vary during the time and due to the java versions.

For start you can refer to the following illustration. It's good to start from `Exception` class since all the direct sub classes are not listed below:

[image]

Comment: I was wondering why a '-1'? Is there something wrong? Or a better solution exists? What is so tempting to give a '-1' and not giving a simple comment for the reason?

Comment: I wasn't the one to give it, but I assume that it's because it doesn't answer the question (`what is exact number of Exception (Built-in) class available in java`) - I don't blame you for not answering it, because it makes little sense as it currently stands; trying to answer lousy questions is usually the easiest way to get downvotes IMO. Also, FWIW: `What is so tempting to give -` and not give comment?` - in the past I commented on my `-1`, just to learn that: a) it's the easiest way to get a flame war started and to get revenge downvotes, a) it's actually discouraged by meta consensus.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like **439**.

Goto: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/allclasses-noframe.html

and do a find for **Exception**